# How to shutdown Ruby XMLRPC server?

Tags: ruby, xml-rpc

I'm testing Ruby XMLRPC support right now. It all works fine, except `XMLRPC::Server#shutdown`.

If I run the following Ruby 1.9.3 test code, it fails to shut down the server on both Windows 7 and OSX 10.7:

```
# server.rb

require "xmlrpc/server"
require 'thread'
Thread.new { sleep 10; $server.shutdown() }
$server = XMLRPC::Server.new( 1234 )
$server.add_handler( "test" ) { true }
$server.serve()

# client.rb

require "xmlrpc/client"
server = XMLRPC::Client.new( "localhost", "/", 1234 )
loop { server.call( "test" ); sleep 0.1 }
```

After ten seconds, the server writes `"INFO  going to shutdown ..."` to stdout, but won't actually shut down and continues to handle incoming requests. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have examined `XMLRPC::Server` source code. It seems a bug/feature that prevents shutdown if client uses connection with `keep-alive` `HTTP` flag.

The workaround is to use `call_async` instead of `call`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed that without incoming requests it shutdowns properly? Also, after you end the client, it will shut down as it should, returning `:Stop` symbol. It waits for the client to stop pumping data before shutting down.

Comment: No, value of $server is initialized. The `"INFO going to shutdown ..."` server response hints that. It just never actually shuts down. Anyway, i have tried to switch this two strings - no difference.

Comment: can you print `$server.__id__` both in the thread and before `.serve()`?

Comment: @famoy 70259918873820 in both cases (same).